# Font from a package (library) not showing up in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, fonts, package, dart-packages

I have a package named Handwriter. It writes text in a custom font. I have the .ttf saved in lib/third_party/. In its pubspec.yaml, I add the font:

```
flutter:
    uses-material-design: true
    fonts:
     - family: FancyHandwriting
       fonts:
        - asset: lib/third_party/FancyHandwriting-Regular.ttf
```

My app imports this package. In its pubspec.yaml, I add Handwriter as a dependency:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  handwriter:
    path: ../handwriter
  model:
    path: ../model
```

However, the font does not show up at all when I use it in my app. Why?

```
final defaultStyle = TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'FancyHandwriting',
      fontSize: 130);
```

Answer (score 8):

**Without** having to re-add the fonts in the package consumer app, you can use:

```
final defaultStyle = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'FancyHandwriting',
  package: 'handwriter',
  fontSize: 130,
);
```

Which is also equivalent to doing:

```
final defaultStyle = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'packages/handwriter/FancyHandwriting',
  fontSize: 130,
);
```

Comment: Whoohoo. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

To use your Flutter Icon font from a custom package, you can follow these steps:

### create a flutter icon font

You can use flutter icon for that https://www.fluttericon.com

### Put the file into your package

Make sure to copy the `.ttf` file **into of the `/lib` folder**.
NOT just assets, as you would do in your root project.

**Example path:**

```
/packages/my_awesome_fontpackage/lib/assets/MyIconFont.ttf
```

(see https://zubairehman.medium.com/how-to-use-custom-fonts-images-in-flutter-package-c2d9d4bfd47a )

### Add the font to your project

Now open your package's `pubspec.yaml` file and add the font as an asset **with package path**:

```
flutter:
  fonts:
  - family:  MyIconFont
    fonts:
      - asset: packages/my_awesome_fontpackage/assets/MyIconFont.ttf
```

(you might have to restart your app and bundling completely for the font to be loaded correctly)

### Now add package declaration to font dart file

Go into the `my_icon_font.dart` file and change the constant `_kFontPkg` there to your package name.

```
class MyIconFont {
  MyIconFont._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'MyIconFont';
  static const String? _kFontPkg = 'my_awesome_fontpackage';

  static const IconData bell = ...
  ....
}
```

Comment: Probably this has changed in the mean time. It worked for me to just set _kFontPkg in the Icon class (keeping the font out of /lib/). Just adding this as I got here myself with that problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/package-fonts you have to declare the package's font in your app's pubspec.yaml:

> Declare the font assets 
>   Now that you’ve imported the package, tell
>   Flutter where to find the fonts from the awesome_package.
>
> To declare package fonts, prefix the path to the font with
>   packages/awesome_package. This tells Flutter to look in the lib folder
>   of the package for the font.

I.e.:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  handwriter:
    path: ../handwriter
  model:
    path: ../model

flutter:
    uses-material-design: true
    fonts:
     - family: FancyHandwriting
       fonts:
        - asset: packages/handwriter/third_party/FancyHandwriting-Regular.ttf
```

Note you're declaring the asset as being from the package - you don't have to make a copy of it in your app's `lib`.

The reasoning behind this is that not all fonts from every package may be used, so this trims down your final app's size.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you must also import/copy the fonts into your font assets directory. In your case make sure you place them in `lib/third_party/`. (See step 1 - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts).